# DataTable filter using data in app.config and c# app

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

Sorry for repeatedly posting same type of questions, but im very confused

Scenario: I have a datatable which fills data into datagrid dynamically/run time as shown below:

```
dt.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value6, value7, value8);
```

Now I have data in `app.config` file which I retrieve as shown below:

```
// app.config file contains string with comma separated and I am splitting it in code

string num1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["crNum"];
string[] values = num1 .Split(',');

foreach (string crNum in values)
{
    // I need code here to delete the entire rows where value1 == crNum 
    // in my above data table dt and also when I reopen/refresh 
    // my c# application I should not see the row deleted before.
}
```

Finally I insert the datatable into the grid

```
myCRGrid.DataSource = dt;
```

I am new to C#, I apologise for such a weird question.

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looping through `dt.Rows` and `Remove()`ing related Row?

Comment: This is not that difficult you need to loop through the datatable rows. also being new does not stop you from doing a google search.. do a simple google search on how to iterate datatable using C#

Comment: im a consfued as to how to delete with condition value1 == crNum

Comment: Actually, you are too close. You got your `rows` and `values` in the columns. Loop through every row and compare those values.

Comment: and you need to write a method that will execute a Sql Delete Command. there are plenty of examples on how to do this as well on the internet..

Comment: ya uteist, but im not able to figure the condition inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (string crNum in values)
            {
                DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("value1 = " + crNum);//assuming value1 is column name
                foreach (DataRow row in rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
```

Comment: So will this will remove all rows in datatable with the values value1 = crNum right ? i will try this and post the result once i test it

Comment: Yes, you need to change the "value1" to proper column name and match it.